# How to find the button definiton in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have this flash template (.fla) with some buttons and definition for those buttons is in an action script (.as) file. I need to find the definition of a particular button in the action script so that I’ll be able to modify the functionality of that particular button.

Is there any easy way to find the definition of button in action script, instead of manually looking over the action script file for the definition?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [getDefinationByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29)??

Comment: i dont knw clearly. I have this button in .fla file and its definition is(i.e. functionality of button) in one of the .as file(i have some 100 .as file). All i need is, i want to look upon the .as file which contains the particular button definition i m looking for so that i ll be able to modify the functionality of the button in .fla file.

Comment: If you have a flash button then it must inherit a class. See the class path in the properties of the button in the IDE & follow the trail then...

Comment: i dont see any class path in the properties.

Comment: What are the values of Class & Base Class in the advanced properties?

Comment: Well then I suppose the export for actionscript is not checked either. And if that is the case then you have no choice but to use search tool to find you button instance names I guess...

Comment: ya.. export for actionscript is not checked too. I am also facing difficulty in using the search tool. i cant find the exact match of the button name in any of the .as file.

Comment: What makes you so sure that there is a refrence of the button in that code? Either way you wont fond the button name but rather the button instance.. ie if the button is on the stage, click on it to get it's name in the property panel. Then search for it.

Comment: there is surely a reference bcoz i ve this app working in my pc. All i need is i just want to do some modifications to the existing functionalities of  this button.

Comment: i have one more doubt.. I want to create a variable(possible global variable) in one action script file and want to use the same variable across all other action script files in the project.

How to create such a variable and how to use the same variable across all .as files??